# Viewing OSM tag information of known element

Tags: openstreetmap, geotag

I'm trying to filter out all the lakes in an area using osmfilter with `natural=water` and `water=lake`.  But some lakes are missing, so I want to view what tags are used for those missing lakes.
For example, I can see a lake graphic in the OSM map, but how can I view the tags of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

- Use the Query Features Tool from the sidebar on the right (the arrow with the question mark, see element 11 at [Browsing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Browsing)) and click on the *outline* of the lake. This will show you all nearby elements.
- Log in with your OSM account and click on edit, this will open your favorite OSM editor for the current area.
- Use the search box to search for the feature if it has a name.
- Click on export to download the current area as XML. This works only for small areas.

Comment: Thank you for listing those methods. The first one is exactly what I'm looking for. Feel stupid I didn't notice that question mark earlier.